# how to add Rating bar in Blogger blog

Tags: blogger, ratingbar

I want to integrate rating bar to my blog, which is hosted on Blogger. and i want to display this rating on google search result, can anyone help ?

i have tried adding rating bar on android, so i want to add rating bar to my blog too. so i can make an android app for my blog and i can control rating through my android app.
please help me
but I'm not sure that what I search. I want to just provide ability for users to rate my blog through android app.

my blog link http://www.xdablogs.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [Raty a JQuery Plugin](http://wbotelhos.com/raty) for five star rating.

Here is another [jQuery Bar Rating](http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/)

Hope you will get some help.

Comment: can i integrate this to my blogger blog??

Comment: ok got it..means i can use raty method of jquery to show rating bar ..:)

Comment: Yes, you can integrate this. Welcome.

Comment: If you found it useful then please accept this answer.

Comment: Does it work directly by adding the code, or you need to control the votes with a database? @LearnPainLess